# Is it possible to add your own text/event-stream Serializer to Spring Boot 2.0.0?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-web, spring-webflux

Currently the only serialization of text/event-stream is done via ServerSentEventHttpMessageWriter.
Is it possible to provide your own writer to change the way the data is serialized (providing a different format besides the SSE format) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom codecs and message readers/writers with a webflux `@Configuration` class; add something like this to your Spring Boot application:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration implements WebFluxConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureHttpMessageCodecs(ServerCodecConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.customCodecs().writer(customHttpMessageWriter);
    }
}
```

The javadoc for `ServerCodecConfigurer`, `CodecConfigurer` (and its inner interfaces) should be useful as well.